# Fill and submit form on another page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a very basic lighting control module, which allows me to turn lights on and off via a web page. The LCM has no API, and I have no access to the LCM other than http. In order to turn lights on and off requires filling in a password form, and clicking a button.

Is it possible to create a web page (hosted on my server), which upon a user clicking an ON or OFF button, accesses the LCM web page, fills in the password field, and submits the form on the LCM page?

This is the form html on the LCM:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon"><html><body>
<p><form method="POST">
IP Address:<input type="text" name="ipValue" value="192.18.1.250"><br>
Subnet Mask:<input type="text" name="submaskValue" value="255.255.255.0"><br>
Gateway:<input type="text" name="gtwValue" value="192.18.1.1"><br>
Building:<input type="text" name="edificioNombre" value="London"><br>
Line:<input type="text" name="lineaNombre" value="Meeting"><br>
Pass Admin:<input type="password" name="adminPass" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" name="ApplyBtn" value="Apply"><input type="submit" name="RebootBtn" value="Reboot"><input type="submit" name="MaxBtn" value="Max"><input type="submit" name="OffBtn" value="Off"><br>
[Fw: v4.1 build 03].
```

Comment: Can you post the form html from LCM page?

Answer (score 1):

A form is nothing more than a easy way which the browser offers to let the users make HTTP requests. What you could do is when you got this data incoming in your `$_POST` array is make a post http request with the same data.

Here is a `PHP` API which allows you to make HTTP request:

http://php.net/manual/it/httprequest.send.php

This will do exactly the same as making the post request besides loading the page.